Was the Russian fleet still a plausible threat for the German fleet in 1917?
According to Anthony Beevor in his book Russia, revolution and civil war, also cited in Wikipedia, the Ice Cruise of the Baltic Fleet was a well-led evacuation operation from Hanko and Helsinski, in Finland, to harbours on the Northen Coast of today's Estonia and Russia (Tallin and Kronstadt).
At the page 256 of my edition, it is said that the Russian Fleet anchored in Finland was strong of 6 battlships, 5 cruisers, 59 destroyers and 12 submarines. This is a very strong fleet, particularly for the number of destroyers which is close to the 61 German torpedo-boats at Jutland, or the 78 British destroyers during the same battle.
There were many opposing battles between German Fleet and the Russian Fleet (supported by some British submarines). Most of the time, the Russians suffered losses (but not definitive, often damaged capital ships) but the Germans as well, and sometimes the Germans plans were countered. But the Russians aligned at best twenty destroyers at the same time.
So my question is: Was the Russian fleet in Finland a significant combat force?
If you put apart of course the question of the loyalty and willingness to fight of the crews. I am wondering because at the same time, in 1917, the Kerenski offensive showed that the Russian army was no more match for the German army.

Just prior to WW1 there was a revolution in warships brought about by HMS Dreadnought making most capital ships obsolete. The result is warships just a decade old might be obsolete, so simply comparing numbers of capital ships is not viable.

‘Many’ battles seems overblown. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Baltic_Sea_operations_of_World_War_I lists perhaps 4 or 5 battles between German and Russian naval forces.

There's a similar issue with comparing destroyers. Torpedo boat destroyers in WW1 could vary from a few hundred tons to almost 1500 tons. A full comparison would be its own question. However, afaik, destroyers did not turn the tide of any major naval battle in WW1.

They were a plausible threat, but not a rival.
At the time, the measure of your navy was in dreadnought battleships, those conforming to the new paradigm of all-big gun battleships with compact steam turbine engines capable of accurate long range gunnery (compared to the previous generation of battleships).
While pre-dreadnought battleships potentially had the armor and firepower to be a threat to a dreadnought, they were too slow, too short ranged, and too inaccurate. By 1917 all German pre-dreadnoughts had been decommissioned or relegated to other duties rather than crew and maintain them. Other navies continued to use them out of necessity; during the Ice Cruise three of the seven Russian battleships were pre-dreadnoughts.
Russia had four 24,000 ton Gangut class dreadnoughts in the Baltic. These had to be countered with German dreadnoughts. Operation Albion in October 1917 saw the Germans bring ten dreadnought battleships.
While destroyers and cruisers were an annoyance, dreadnought battleships at the time could only be countered with other dreadnought battleships. Destroyers were small and torpedoes were slow and inaccurate and could be countered by other small ships. Cruisers simply did not have the armor nor firepower nor range to stand up to a dreadnought in a gun fight. Fleets had not developed the tactics and communications to coordinate all these smaller craft.
The Russian Baltic Fleet of 1917
The Russian Navy is always divided between the Baltic Sea, Black Sea, Arctic Ocean, and Pacific. We necessarily have to look at just the Imperial Russian Baltic Fleet vs (potentially) the entire very modern German High Seas Fleet.
The Russian Navy in WW1 had several handicaps compared to other great powers. It had been devastated by the Russo-Japanese War just a decade prior. A revolution in warship design had just occurred with the launch of HMS Dreadnought in 1906 rendering existing capital ship designs obsolescent. And their country underwent several revolutions which included mutinies amongst the Baltic Fleet leaving the Baltic Fleet disorganized and at a low state of readiness.
As mentioned, Russia had four 24,000 ton Gangut class dreadnoughts in the Baltic. They had no battlecruisers.
Operation Albion and the Battle of Moon Sound
While the German High Seas Fleet was concentrated and much larger, they were stretched thin in 1917. Four Russian dreadnoughts could be a threat depending what resources Germany was able to bring to the Baltic.
They had been handed a demoralizing defeat at the Battle of Jutland in 1916 and were still licking its wounds. Germany had to fight the Russian Navy, the French Navy, the British Navy, and soon the US Navy, and also relieve the blockade of Germany as best they could while also attempting to blockade the Allies.
For what Germany could feasibly bring against the Russian Baltic Fleet in 1917, we need only to look at what they actually did bring against the Russian Baltic Fleet in Oct 1917 in Operation Albion and the subsequent Battle of Moon Sound: ten dreadnoughts, one battlecruiser, nine light cruisers, 50 destroyers, and six submarines. Against this Russia brought only two pre-dreadnought battleships, three cruisers, 21 destroyers, and three submarines.
Noticeably absent were the four Gangut dreadnoughts cooling their heels in Petrograd in the nervous atmosphere just prior to the October Revolution. Even had they shown up for the battle, they would be facing ten German dreadnoughts.
As is common for the time, Germany took more damage from mines than warships during the operation.

Fantastic answer. I would perhaps also add that Russian naval doctrine was also in shambles. 1905 showed how ineffectual Russian naval command was (remember that it was the Baltic fleet that was sent around the world to Tsushima) and the intervening years were not long enough to completely pivot away from every problem they had. On top of mutinous sailors, you would also have inept officers.

@SPavel, the Baltic fleet was sent to Tsushima because the Pacific fleet had spent the prior year slowly getting sunk by the Japanese.

@Mark as opposed to the much more efficient Baltic fleet which achieved the same thing in just a day or two?

To be fair, at the start of the war the German Baltic units were all pre-dreadnought ships to counter the Russian fleet including the Ganguts which, as Russia's first dreadnoughts, really were not up to the standards of a 1914-new dreadnought. It is true that, should it be necessary, the Germanys could pull dreadnoughts from the High Seas fleet. through the Kiel canal. By October 1917 the High Seas Fleet could spare dreadnoughts for Baltic operations since they were not going to venture out against the British again.
